# Previous Expansion Encroaches on Property Line

Tags: walls

I bought a property with two structures in 2014. I later found that the second structure cannot be occupied as a residence because a later expansion encroaches on the property line, making it non-conforming.

I want to remove the expansion. The builder created the addition by extending existing load-bearing walls and constructing a new clear-span exterior wall. If I remove the add-on, I will have a 5' setback the city code requires.

I have been unable to hire an architect to provide necessary plans to show how I will support the original structure because all local architects are too busy, and the job is small. How can I get a set of plans to submit my project to the city?

Comment: This will require onsite inspection so I think you're going to have to wait until someone frees up. If you've got the experience, you might be able to draw it up and have firm  approve it  but they'd still need an onsite visit.

Comment: Have you tried an engineer instead of architect?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get a set of plans to submit my project to the city?

You either draw them yourself or hire someone else to do it.  I'm not aware of any "magic" solution that will get you what you need any other way.